# How many massive black holes exist in AGN-type galaxies?

Tags: observational-astronomy, supermassive-black-hole, active-galaxy

Most galaxies have a massive (i.e., $m \gtrsim 10^5$ M$_{\odot}$) black hole in their center.

Is it known 1) theoretically and 2) observationally what fraction of these massive black holes (maybe as a function of redshift) will/should/do exist in active-galactic-nuclei? I've seen numbers as low as 1% - 10%, but could not find a definitive source. References that lead to the answers of these questions are greatly appreciated.